# locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, core-location, cllocationmanager

I created an app that comunicates with beacons and manages a map and a locationManager.

The problem is that when the map is being displayed, the heading calibration screen appears too much often even I implement this method of the locationManager delegate to return NO. But it never gets called:

```
- (BOOL)locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration:(CLLocationManager *)manager
```

This is the configuration of my locationManager:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}

[self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
[self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:1];
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
[self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

I also have a MKMapView set to `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading`, which I saw other questions in StackOverflow that pointed that it might interfere in the locationManager delegate methods.
In this app it is important to track user position in the map and to have my locationManager working at the same time.

Don’t know if it is a bug or if there exists a solution to all this.

Thanks in advance!